# efficient code in terms of time of memory: string or file handler?

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I have a python program which has at least 5 different modules parsing for data in a log file.. Is it advisable to copy the file contents in to a string and share it between the functions or open the file each time with in the function ?

Comment: HDD is slower than RAM. Thus, load it into memory. Whatever it is, this is premature optimisation anyway

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on what you are doing. However, you should be aware that your OS will typically cache the most recent reads from a file, so it may make no difference to you which method you choose.

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable comments..